# "Browsing session has ended or is invalid" when loading Canvas in DX scratch org

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, canvas, scratch-org

I followed [this Salesforce tutorial](http://ccoenraets.github.io/salesforce-developer-advanced/Using-Canvas.html) to get a Canvas connection working in a DX scratch org.

I'm quite sure I configured everything right but the Canvas on the page always shows

> Canvas - 09H1x0000008Phf Your browsing session has ended or is
>   invalid. Please re-login to Salesforce.com again.

**I also tried:** When I read this thread ["Canvas app invalid session when using frontdoor authentication"](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AmRnIAK) I also tried to create a real user in my scratch org and logged in from the regular Login form. Nothing happened.

**Note: I sometimes read Lightning enabled orgs don't work with Canvas. Is that true?!**

[image]

Comment: Any updates here?  Running into the same error message but on a managed package

Comment: Same here, running into this issue in a non-scratch org intermittently.